# Taking a users string input, comparing it to my string and output a bootbox dialog if they match

Tags: jquery, html, twig

I need to create a form that allows a user to input an answer to a question with the answer they need to enter being [Cat, Rabbit, Cow, Bull, Dog]. If they get the correct answer the JQuery should return a bootbox dialog letting them know they have answered the question correct with a link to the next question.

I have provided my form below:

```
{% block main %}
<form name="answer" id="uanswer" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="answer" name="answer" placeholder="Enter Your Answer Here" style="text-align: center; width: 300px;">
    <input type="button" value="Check My Answer" id="useranswer">
</form>    
{% endblock main %}
```

and this is my JQuery:

```
{% block onload %}
$("#useranswer").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    answer = $("#answer").val();

    if (answer.toLowerCase() == "[cat, rabbit, cow, bull, dog]"){
        bootbox.dialog({
            closeButton: false,
            onEscape: false,
            title: "<h1>That's Correct!</h1>",
            message: "Notice in a hashSet that the data in the set is in the same order that it is added in. Now lets move onto TreeSets",
            buttons: {
                success:{
                    label: "Next Question",
                    callback: function(result) {
                        if (result) {
                            window.location.href = 'http://localhost/webproject/stude/exampletest3/';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    } else {
        bootbox.alert("That's Incorrect!")
    }
});
{% endblock onload %}
```

however when I press the submit button nothing happens on the page at all and I'm unsure as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('#useranswer') is a button, so you should write **click** instead of **submit** event as follows:

```
$("#useranswer").on("click", function(event) {
```